# Crickets with live babies

Tags: entomology

From what I understand of Crickets, they lay their eggs in dirt and hop away and that is their parenthood.

But in the past month (since I moved into this apartment) I have found 1 adult cricket and half a dozen tiny baby crickets in my bathtub on THREE SEPARATE OCCASIONS.

There have been times I have found other adult crickets in the tub, I have never found a baby cricket in the tub alone.

Something is going on here that doesn't track, an adult cricket could easily get into the standard 18 inch-ish high bathtub, but these baby crickets are about 2mm long and can jump upwards of about 3 inches from my testing.

Why/How are they traveling together?  What is the gestation on crickets?  Is it short enough that she lays the eggs at night and they hatch by mid morning?   Are they coming up the drain?  Carrying their brood on their backs because this is Arizona and they learned it by watching scorpions?  I need answers! This is the weirdest mystery of quarantine, and it must be solved.